# Deserialization with QTextStream?

Tags: qt, serialization, deserialization, qsettings

Need: Read/Write a struct of standard Qt types from/to a human readable/editable file.

Tried: QSettings. It was fairly easy to get it working. Problem: QSettings automatically calls QSettings::sync() periodically, and at dtor. I am required to ensure that the settings file is only updated on request, and that run-time data structure is only modified on request.

Tried: QDataStream. Problem: Not human readable/editable.

Tried: Manual serialization and deserialization, using standard readline and QString::toInt() and such. I now have to support types that QSettings supports, but that QString does not have 'toFoo()' methods for. This way would be MUCH, MUCH more coding.

**Is there a way to serialize and deserialize human-readable data without using QSettings?** Everything about it is against requirements. The files are supposed to be named differently. Access is supposed to be controlled differently.

It would probably be enough, if there was simply a way to block sync(). We can probably work around anything else. It's "sync" that gives me the most problems.

Comment: You could use `QSettings` not as a member variable of your class, but a local variable which is created or deleted in different places of your code depending on your requirements.

Comment: What problems do you get with `QTextStream` ?

Comment: If you want human readable it's probably worthwhile doing your own serialisation with JSON. There's an example here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html

Comment: @Tarod That might work. I might be able to protect file by changine file name in QSettings, and protect QSettings instance... By carefully paying attention to the event loop. If I can guarantee we won't re-enter it between calls, that might be enough.  
@ SaZ It doesn't deserialize automatically or for all the types QSettings does, AFAICT.  
@ NicholasSmith If I had to resort to manually creating the serialization format, we wouldn't use JSON. I don't think those classes actually help me. I still have to write read()/write().

Comment: @SaburoutaMishima Yep, the idea would be to implement by yourself a sort of synchronization because as you said, you require to update the file on request.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code for QSettings, it appears that it performs human-readable serialization-deserialization in a unique way. It does not appear that this facility exists in other parts of Qt. Also, there are numerous points where the file-system is automatically altered.

This is not possible in Qt.